# Convert an annotation-based JPA application into persistence.xml based?

Tags: java, spring

*Warning: It is exactly the opposite of the common direction. This time I am looking for a simple way to convert back an annotation-based Java application to an xml-based. This question is _not_ a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603152/tool-to-convert-spring-xml-config-to-java-config).*

So, I have a JPA application there, but I would like to convert it back to use xml as its ORM mapping. Do I need to do this with hand or there is also a better/faster/simpler way as well?

Comment: Curious... why do you want to go back?

Comment: @Antoniossss I have a good set of tools working on xml files, but don't have the same features for annotations. My goal were to re-construct the xml ORM files automatically from the annotations and then using these xmls with my xslt & modelling scripts.

Comment: I do not know any other way than doing it by hand ... But I won't do that without serious reasons because I once tried to use JPA xml mapping and fell back to using annotations for lack of examples.